# How to extend NSString with function which returns only suffixed numbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have array of words where every word contains at the end some number ( for example test203, test12 ). I have to sort array of those kind a words based on that suffix number. Is possible to extend NSString class with function which would return that number as int ?

Comment: Do you know how many digits the number is? Do you know if there can be other digits in the middle of the string?

Comment: Sounds like you need a category on NSString ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own class with a method that would return `int` and take `NSString` as a parameter. For example:

```
+(int)getSuffix:(NSString*)theString {
    NSString *newString = [[theString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
            [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
            componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [newString intValue];
}
```

And then you can call this method with your strings:

```
[SuffixClass getSuffix:@"test12"];
```

This will return 12

Comment: That may surprise you in that it might include characters beyond ASCII numbers. More accurate and predictable to create an explicit set and do string normalization before applying the set.